# How Do I Edit Database Records In A DataGridView Using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datagridview

I'm so close on this one, but I need a little help.  I have a simple WinForms app that uses LINQ to SQL to grab data that needs to be reviewed from a database and stuff it into a `DataGridView`.  That part works great, but the connection I can't seem to make is how to get the data back into the database when things change.

Here's what I have so far:

```
db = new SiteDataDataContext();
src = new BindingSource();
src.DataSource = GetSitesPendingApproval(); // Returns IQueryable<Site>.
dataGridView1.DataSource = src;
dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = true;
dataGridView1.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter;
```

I have two actions I want to be able to take:

1. When the `checkbox` for the `boolean` value `IsActive` (`DataGridView.Columns`[7]) is checked/unchecked I want changes to be sent to the database.
2. When a record is deleted from the `datagridview`, I want it to also be deleted from the database.

I'm obviously missing some sort of binding, submit, merge, append, or cell changed event handler, but I haven't been able to figure out the connection to send back the changes.  If it's easier to just make all the changes and then hit some sort of submit button to send it all back that's fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding an event handler for the UserDeletingRow event that uses the id on the row to remove the row from the database?

```
private void DataGrid_UserDeletingRow(object sender,
                                           DataGridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    TableCell itemCell = e.Item.Cells[0]; // assumes id is in column 0

    int id = int.Parse(item.Text); // assumes it's non-null

    using (var dc = new SiteDataDataContext())
    {
         var site = dc.Sites.Where(s => s.ID == id).SingleOrDefault();

         if (site != null)
         {
             try
             {
                dc.Sites.DeleteOnSubmit( site );
                dc.SubmitChanges();
                dataGridView1.Bind();
             }
             catch (SqlException)
             {
                e.Cancel = true;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

You might also provide an error message if the delete failed, but how you do it would depend on your application.

Comment: Not quite how I would have expected to have to do it (figured I'd get more for free with data binding), but that'll do the trick.  Thank you.

Comment: For WebForms there is a LinqDataSource that you could bind to that gives you the ability to do a delete more easily, though I suspect it just does something like my example on the back end. I didn't see an analog for WinForms.

Comment: You have "get id from row column" ... how is this done?

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle examine the row and pull the id from the column that contains it.  You'd have to make sure to include it in a (perhaps hidden) column in the grid view.

Comment: Can I do that somehow from the row object cast from the sender? The row object has a number of options (methods and properties) on the intellisense but I'm not seeing anything that would reveal or help me get the ID of the row to update.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle looks like I had the wrong class for the event args. I've updated and give an (assumed) example of how to get the id, which I assumed was in column 0 of the row.

Comment: Erp @tvanfosson it looks like the TableCell class is part of WebControls, I'm in WinForms.  Also what's the item object you have there? item.Text Also the event args (e) does not contain an Item class or namespace. This is definitely not working.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle ah - in that case you should be able to look in the Cells property of the `DataGridViewRow` (`e.Row` on the DataGridViewRowEventArgs passed as the event args)

Comment: @tvanfosson I found e.ColumnIndex and e.RowIndex. There is no such thing as SiteDataContext or any class like that, not sure what that is. I googled that and came up with just this post.

Comment: @tvanfosson oops realized that was the Linq dbml name.

Comment: @tvanfosson I'm getting closer. Here's my question posted with the existing code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925687/c-sharp-visual-studio-how-do-i-update-a-db-from-edit-with-datagridview-using-li